# How does a roller coaster car stay on the track on a curve

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, curvature

Say a roller coaster car is going up a ramp to a drop. At some point it needs to traverse a curve to get to the drop. In general, since the car is constrained to the rail, how is it able to move around on curves without breaking the car? Does there exist some kind of free motion for the wheels to move a little bit? Otherwise it seems like the car would bend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google search "roller coaster wheels" brings up this picture (from [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Train_(roller_coaster))):

[image]

As you can see, the "wheels" are really an assembly of three different pairs of wheels: the ones from above, supporting the normal weight; a pair below, that stops the car flying off the track in negative g curves; and ones on the side that, in conjunction with a similar pair on the other side of the tracks, holds the car on the rails laterally. Clearly, the rails are circular in cross section with all the supports on the inside in order to accommodate these wheels.

Note also the giant swivel bolt in the center, near the top. This is where the entire assembly can swivel so the wheels can deal with curvature of the rails. I suspect that there is a further degree of freedom (not shown) just as there is on train cars, where the entire assembly (wheels from both sides joined together) can swivel about a common vertical axis - and another one to swivel about a central horizontal axis (see how the two sets of wheels in the picture below are at very different angles - you need lots of degrees of freedom to achieve that). You can't see the pivots, but you can see the motion, in this picture from
http://www.ultimaterollercoaster.com/coasters/reviews/typhoon/typhoon8.shtml

[image]

A further cartoon to explain how the first axle allows the car to accommodate convex or concave tracks:

[image]

As you can see, the wheels accommodate the curvature - and because they grip the rail on three sides (four, if you look at sets of wheels on both sides of the track) they can hold the car in place on any curve regardless of the direction of the required force.

Comment: Take DodoBird's example picture and make the curve convex. Does the assembly have the ability to push itself inward? Or am I thinking about this the wrong way? It's hard for me to visualize this in my head. I guess I'm also trying to think of a normal car doing this on an upward hill.

Comment: Awesome illustration! I'm guessing that the wheels would lift the cart a bit higher so that it doesn't actually go into the cart :).

Does this illustration also apply to a simple automobile going up a similar hill since it doesn't have the same wheel assembly?

Comment: I did not try to draw to scale - thinking the principle was more important than the engineering execution. Cars have simple axes, and typically don't require the additional degrees of freedom. The picture that @dodobird drew is all you need for a "simple automobile".

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything wrong with this image (not even considering the suspension on the wheels)?

[image]

Comment: No but on a roller coaster rail the wheels are enclosed by rails. In your picture the car can more freely move.

Comment: Note OP also states *traverse a curve to get to the drop* which means a concave shape instead of the convex one you've got.